# Parallelism in Spark-Kafka integration

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to ask what exactly `setMaster("local[2]")` and `Map("test1"->5)` means in the following code

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[2]")
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test1" -> 5))
```

As far as I know `setMaster("local[2]")` means there will be two spark thread. Does it means two master nodes or worker nodes? And `Map("test1" -> 5))` means the number of partitions a topic has. Does this number should be equal to the one mentioned with `local[]`? Or if I am wrong, can someone explain both of them more better.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one node by specifying local as master. It's both a master (a driver) and a worker (executor)

Regarding the map, documentation says

> Map of (topic_name -> numPartitions) to consume. Each partition is consumed in its own thread

You ideally, yes, have as many possible consumers as you have partitions for max parallelism from Kafka, but if you have less, it'll consume data in a round-robin fashion

Answer (score 0):

1. `Local[2]` means that you will have 2 threads as a worker. In general, local[k] means: Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine). Always keep in mind that, in Spark, parallelism is a Worker level.
2. `Map("test1" -> 5)` means [[per-topic number of Kafka partitions to consume]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/streaming-kafka-integration.html). Essentially, it is saying that topic `"test1"` has 5 partitions to be consumed.